# can any one get my database referernce and edit on it in firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am using firebase database in my android app . I found a warning from firebase console saying that making the writing and reading rules for my database isn't secure. I was wondering if some one can access my data in the database outside the app by getting a reference to the database in some way, because in the app users can't edit any thing that I am not allowing them to edit so will setting the rules to be true is dangerous for me or not ? and if yes so why it's dangerous and not secure?and in my app I allow the users to write posts so How can I allow all users in the app to write posts in the app with a secure rules?

Answer (score 2):

If your security rules are not set properly, **anyone in the world can read and write your database**, regardless of what your app does internally.  There are two things you should know:

First, the only way to fully control access to your database, when it's being accessed directly by client apps, is via security rules.  You should expect that anyone is able to attempt to read and write your database without your client app, perhaps by the REST API.  All someone has to know is the name of your Firebase project, which is baked into your app and easily visible.

Second, you should expect that your client app can be reverse engineered and altered.  Code in the hands of users is not inherently secure.  It's not a good idea to attempt to protect the access to your database using only the code in your app.

Comment: I would add that client update schedules are more troublesome than client apps being reverse engineered.

Comment: Without seeing your rules and understanding how your app and users make use of the data, there's nothing else to say.  Perhaps try asking another question with enough detail to identify a specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with this misunderstanding a lot. I believe you are mixing concerns, tell me if you're not.

**Security** who can connect to my database?

The answer is anyone. Firebase doesn't require an SQL user or anything, just connect.

**Data Consistency** who can do what? *This is where you should focus*

Use firebase security rules, validation rules, and functions, to guarantee data consistency.

In sum, your backend should not allow your clients to misbehave.